# Closed form of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left( \tan^{-1} \frac{4n-1}{2} - \tan^{-1} \frac{4n-3}{2} \right)$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

**Problem:**

Find closed form of $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left( \tan^{-1} \frac{4n-1}{2} - \tan^{-1} \frac{4n-3}{2} \right)$$

without using complex-analysis

I think this is not a telescope, taylor series. Is there any nice idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\sum_{n\geq 1}\left[\arctan\frac{2}{4n-3}-\arctan\frac{2}{4n-1}\right]=\sum_{n\geq 1}\left[\arg(4n-3+2i)-\arg(4n-1+2i)\right] $$
can be written as 
$$\sum_{n\geq 1}\arctan\frac{4}{7-16n+16n^2}=\text{Im}\log\prod_{n\geq 1}\left(1+\frac{4i}{7-16n+16n^2}\right)$$
or
$$ \text{Im}\log\left[\frac{\cosh\frac{\pi}{2}+i\sinh\frac{\pi}{2}}{\sqrt{2}\cosh(\pi\sqrt{3}/4)}\right]=\color{red}{\arctan\tanh\frac{\pi}{2}}. $$
This might feel as cheating since we have exploited Weierstrass products, which pretty much belong to the realm of Complex Analysis. An alternative approach comes from noticing that we have to compute
$$ \sum_{n\geq 1}\int_{2n-3/2}^{2n-1/2}\frac{dx}{x^2+1} = \frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{R(x)}{x^2+1}\,dx $$
where $R(x)$ is an even rectangle wave. Switching to Fourier or Laplace transforms, the last integral is converted into $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(x)e^{-|x|}\,dx$ or $\int_{0}^{+\infty}g(e^s)\sin(s)\,ds$, which are manageable and lead (of course) to the same outcome.

Comment: The function $2\arctan\tanh\frac{x}{2}$ is called the [Gudermannian function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gudermannian_function), so your result is $\frac12\operatorname{gd}(\pi)$.

Comment: Agreed.$\phantom{}$

Comment: Please be forgiving on this relatively new user, and explain the jump to the last step... most people here are not as smart as you.

Comment: The products $$\prod_{n\geq 1}\left(1\pm \frac{C}{p(n)}\right)$$ where $p(n)$ is a quadratic polynomial can be computed from the Weierstrass products for the sine and cosine functions. I skipped the intermediate computations since they are just messy.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel He's a Math-Guru !!!.